# Jump past the heat death of the universe

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for the title and author of a short story I read a while back. It was set on a spaceship with a small crew which had gotten lost and was trying to get back home. However, a side effect of the cold sleep, "indistinguishable from death" necessary for travel was cumulative brain damage, so the crew was slowly dying.

The brain damage caused by the sleep impacted crew members differently, with folks from high altitude environments (like the Maasai Mara) withstanding the impact of the jumps better than others. It was a small crew (maybe 5 people?) and I think the other crew member that survived the longest was from the Andes.

The story ends with the last surviving crew member (I think a Maasai woman?) setting up a jump that would take more time than the universe would exist.

I believe it was within the last 10 years. I think I had heard it on [StarShipSofa](http://www.starshipsofa.com/) and then found it online.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you be a bit more specific about when you read this?  Where was it; in an anthology, a magazine or online?  Was the brain damage a function of the number of times going into cold sleep or the total amount of time spent there?

Comment: I believe it was within the last 10 years. I _think_ I had heard it on http://www.starshipsofa.com and then found it online. I think the brain damage was related to the number of times going into cold sleep.

Comment: I should've added that the brain damage caused by the sleep impacted crew members differently, with folks from high altitude environments (like the Maasai Mara) withstanding the impact of the jumps better than others.  It was a small crew (maybe 5 people?) and the other crew member that survived the longest was from the Andes?

Comment: It has already been done for your, but you can [edit] your question to add any new information.

Comment: Did the author mention  "heat death"? I'm remembering a story where a character jumped through the Big Crubch into the next cycle of the Universe.

Comment: No, that was my interpretation -- it was more that in the last jump, the age of the universe as estimated by the ship's computer was "?" (or infinity -- I don't recall exactly).  Jumping through the Big Crunch might have been "Tau Zero" by Poul Anderson (or the short story it was based on, "To Outlive Eternity")